# Sort an array of 0s 1s & 2s with o(1)

Tags: java, sorting

Can we sort an array of 0s 1s & 2s with O(1) complexity.

`{0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,2,2,0,0}`

Comment: No sorting will never be smaller than O(n), because you have to at least check if the array is already sorted or not.

Comment: @garima Do you know what o(1) is?

Comment: If you think about what you have to do, you'd realize there's no way to have O(1) complexity on a sort, as Icewind has said.  It doesn't matter what you are sorting, you always have to at a minimum verify it is in order, which is O(n), and usually sort it, which ranges in complexity based on its methodology.

Comment: Well, you can sort this particular array `return {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,}`. Not sure if it counts. And even this takes O(n) to return. You can't do it in O(1) with out any prior knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort the whole array in O(1) simply because a sorting algorithm is always dependent on n.

Have look at this quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Classification) regarding computional time of sort algorithms:

> Computational complexity (worst, average and best behavior) of element comparisons in terms of the 
>   size of the list (n). For typical serial sorting algorithms good
>   behavior is O(n log n), with parallel sort in O(log2 n), and bad
>   behavior is O(n2). (See Big O notation.) Ideal behavior for a serial
>   sort is O(n), but this is not possible in the average case, optimal
>   parallel sorting is O(log n). Comparison-based sorting algorithms,
>   which evaluate the elements of the list via an abstract key comparison
>   operation, need at least O(n log n) comparisons for most inputs.